# always scroll to a scrollable div to bottom by always scrolling a very large number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a scrollable div which would load conversation dynamically through ajax, and i would like to scroll the div always to the bottom with fresh conversation coming in.

can I simply use

```
 $(".conversation").scrollTop(1000000000);
```

to fulfill this task?
will it has any disadvantages even though what you actually need is 100. I wonder whenever it scrolls to the bottom, and it won't bother to scroll another 9999999900?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollTop:

"If set to a value greater than the maximum that the content can be scrolled, scrollTop is set to the maximum."

So shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the div's `scrollTop` to its `scrollHeight`:

```
$(".conversation").scrollTop($(".conversation")[0].scrollHeight);
```

This way you could have a div that is 1000000001px high without having to change code and it looks a little better than a random large number.

Comment: I love the thought of a 1000000001px-high div.  Maybe using `Number.MAX_VALUE` would handle any possibility, with less typing.